# Stored information between browsing sessions - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, google-chrome-headless

I am writing SpecFlow/Selenium tests with headless Google Chrome in `--incognito` and I would like to know if the headed or headless instances will be more separated than when I use Chrome as a desktop browser.

Specifically, I have two tests running at the same time which require accessing the same site and performing the login steps of two different users. Will those browsers have unique, separate logins or will they behave like incognito does for me as a user - that is, will the first login be recognised by the second instance?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: They appear to be segregated, but looks can be deceiving.

Comment: Launch two incognito instances, sign into the first one, refresh the second one. Are you logged into the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both completely isolated from eachother.

You can verify this by running either, and then checking for stored cookies or login information.

To answer directly, no, the first login will not be recognized by the second instance.